# Electrode for methanol

Tags: electrochemistry, catalysis

Could you advice an electrode for electrophoretic deposition in methanol which won't spoil methanol and also wont be spoiled by methanol. I googled a bit and found that
1 copper, platinum and gold are catalysts of methanol oxidation
2 aluminum reacts with methanol
3 silicon has poor conductivity...

What can you advice?

Answer (score 2):

Glassy carbon may be a good choice. Looking at [this](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/elan.1140071207/abstract), electrooxidation of methanol doesn't seem to be possible at reasonable potentials on glassy carbon, and it's a common working electrode material, relatively inexpensive, durable, and available in many shapes and sizes. Graphite could also work, though it may need to be replaced periodically as graphite electrodes tend to be less robust.